# How to throttle broadcast events in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, events, broadcast, pusher

I'm using some events that are broadcasted through the implementation of `ShouldBroadcast`.

Is there any way of throttling those events to be broadcasted the right way? What I want is, from a bunch of events that are created, only a few are broadcasted, depending on when they are created.

When I try to throttle in `broadcastOn()`, it gives an exception, as I don't return a Channel, though, if I return, it will be broadcasted.

My `broadcastOn()` function

```
public function broadcastOn()
    {
        $run = true;

        Redis::throttle(class_basename($this) . 'Broadcast')
            ->allow(config('app.events.throttle.allow'))
            ->every(config('app.events.throttle.every'))
            ->then(
                function () {
                    info(class_basename($this));
                    //                    return new Channel('entries');
                },
                function () use (&$run) {
                    info(class_basename($this) . ' discarded');
                    $run = false;
                }
            );

        return $run ? new Channel('entries') : null;
    }
```

When the new channel is not initialized, it gives the exception below:

```
local.ERROR: Expected at least one channel
 {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastException(code: 0): Expected at least one channel
 at /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/PusherBroadcaster.php:119)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Broadcasting/BroadcastEvent.php(48): Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster->broadcast(Array, 'App\\Events\\Entr...', Array)
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent->handle(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\PusherBroadcaster))
#2 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#8 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent))
#9 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Bus/Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/CallQueuedHandler.php(49): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastEvent), false)
#11 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Jobs/Job.php(88): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Array)
#12 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(331): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#13 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(281): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#14 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Worker.php(118): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob), 'redis', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#15 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(102): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('redis', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#16 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/WorkCommand.php(86): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('redis', 'default')
#17 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Console/WorkCommand.php(46): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#18 [internal function]: Laravel\Horizon\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#19 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(32): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#20 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(90): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#21 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(34): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#22 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(576): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#23 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(183): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#24 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#25 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(170): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#26 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(921): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#27 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Laravel\Horizon\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#28 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#29 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(90): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#30 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(133): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#31 /Users/brunomasquio/code/docigp/artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#32 {main}
"}
```

Comment: You could use [broadcast conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcast-conditions) to do what you want? Otherwise I would suggest placing the throttling code where you fire the events/broadcast (which might mean to "manually" broadcast instead of using broadcastable events),

Comment: The `broadcastWhen()` seems to solve it. I'm going to try that.

If I throttle where I fire the events, it's going to be slow when a request is discarded, since the process waits inside the throttling function.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. I also added my comment as answer for you to accept if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [broadcast conditions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#broadcast-conditions) and place your throttling code in the `broadcastWhen()`.

Otherwise I would suggest placing the throttling code where you fire the events/broadcast (which might mean to "manually" broadcast instead of using broadcastable events), however as you pointed out in the comments that won't work for your use case but might for others reading this back.